# Find the best staircase to maximize the sum

Tags: fastest-algorithm

Given an \$n \times n\$ matrix of integers, The task is to find the optimal dividing line that maximizes the sum of the integers on the same side as the top left corner.  The dividing line should be connected and made up of only vertical and horizontal lines.  For an example with a non-optimal dividing line:

[image]

```
[[ 3,  0,  2, -3, -3, -1, -2,  1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -2, -3, -2,  2, -2, -3],
 [ 1,  3,  3,  1,  1, -3, -1, -1,  3,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  2,  1, 2,  2, -1, -1],
 [-1,  0,  3,  1,  1,  3, -2,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1,  1,  2, -3, -2, 1, -2,  0,  0],
 [-3,  2,  2,  3, -2,  0, -1, -1,  3, -2, -2,  0,  2,  1,  2,  2, 1, -1, -3, -3],
 [-2, -2,  1, -3, -2, -1,  3,  2,  3, -3,  2,  3,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  3, -2, -1],
 [ 0,  0, -2, -3,  2,  3,  2,  2, -3,  0, -1, -1,  1, -2, -1,  3, 3,  0,  1,  0],
 [ 1,  2,  2, -1,  2,  0,  1, -2,  1,  2, -1, -3, -3,  2,  0,  0, -3, -1, -2,  2],
 [-1,  2,  2,  2,  0,  1, -3,  0,  0,  1, -2,  3,  3, -1,  2,  0, -1,  0, -1, -2],
 [ 3,  2,  0, -1, -2, -3, -2,  2, -1, -3, -3,  2, -3,  3,  1, -3, 0,  0, -2,  2],
 [ 2,  2, -1, -2,  2,  0, -2,  1,  0, -3, -2,  2, -2,  1, -1, -3, 3, -3, -3, -1],
 [ 2, -1, -2, -1, -3,  0, -3,  3, -3,  0,  1,  2, -3, -1, -3,  0, 3, -1, -2,  1],
 [ 0, -1, -2,  1,  0,  2,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1, -2, -2,  3,  2,  1, -2, -3,  0,  3],
 [-1,  1, -2, -1,  3,  1, -2,  1,  1,  3, -2, -3,  2, -2, -2,  2, 3, -3,  0, -3],
 [ 3, -1,  1,  1, -3,  0, -1, -2,  3, -3, -3, -2, -2,  2,  1,  1, 0,  2, -3, -3],
 [-2, -2, -1, -2,  1, -1,  2,  3,  3, -3, -2,  2, -1,  2, -2, -3, 1, -3, -2,  3],
 [-2,  2,  3, -3, -3,  3,  0,  2, -3, -3,  2, -3,  0, -1, -3,  3, -2, -2,  2, -3],
 [-3,  1, -1, -2,  1, -3,  0,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0, -2,  0,  0, -2, -1,  1,  1,  2],
 [-1, -1,  0,  1, -2,  2, -3,  2, -2, -2,  3, -2,  2,  0, -3, -1, -3, -2, -3, -2],
 [ 2,  0,  2,  3,  0,  2, -1, -2,  2, -2,  3,  1,  3,  0,  3, -2, -3, -3,  0,  2],
 [-3, -3,  3, -3,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0, -3,  2,  2, -1,  0, -3, 1, -3,  1,  1]]
```

**The complication is that the number of horizontal lines is restricted to be at most \$k\$, for some integer parameter \$k\$.** In the picture above there are 4 horizontal lines within the dividing line. The dividing line can start at any point on the left or bottom edge and end at a different edge.

## Worked examples

Take the example matrix above and \$k=1\$.  First, the sum of the entire matrix is -76 so we would already do better by including none of it.  If we start the horizontal line from the left edge then the optimal has score 26 by including the first 10 rows and 3 columns.  We should now consider starting on the bottom edge with a vertical line, then a horizontal line and potentially another vertical line. In this case that turns out not to help and 26 is the optimal sum.

Let us take a smaller example with \$k=1\$ again.

```
  [[-3, -2,  3,  2, -2],
   [ 3, -2, -2, -5, -3],
   [ 0,  3,  1,  1, -3],
   [ 1,  1,  2,  1, -1],
   [ 1,  1,  1, -3,  3]]
```

Here the optimal solution is to include the first 3 columns and then only first row for the next column. This gives a sum of 10.  The dividing line has one horizontal part and two vertical ones.

> How quickly can this problem be solved when \$k\$ is an input parameter along with the matrix?

The winning criterion will be asymptotic time complexity. As there are two parameters, you can assume \$k \leq \sqrt{n}\$ when giving your final time complexity. So a complexity of \$O(n^2+k)\$ would translate to \$O(n^2 + \sqrt{n}) = O(n^2)\$.

## Further details

The dividing line will always go either right or up.

Comment: Must the line go right and up? Or can it make turns if it gives a better sum?

Comment: Can the line be self-intersecting?

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning it in the question, or perhaps include in a test case since I thought from reading it that you weren't allowed to go up and down.

Comment: Perhaps I am misssing something, but if you can go both up and down, isn't this equivalent to solving each 1d column separately?  Find the best row for column, move right.  Find best row division for column 2, go up or down to it, go right.  Etc.

Comment: I changed my mind and simplified the problem. The dividing line must always go right or up.

Comment: @Jonah the detail is that you are only allowed k horizontal lines. I simplified the problem by only allowing right and up moves.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think the first example is wrong, the fourth column shouldn't be included, because (-3) + 1 + (-2) = -4, so, this is wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena it’s not meant to be an optimal dividing line. I will update the examples later today.

Comment: I suspect a DP grid approach using prefix sums will work.

Comment: @qwr  That would be great. What complexity do you expect?

Comment: I didn't actually think of a solution. But column prefix sums would be computed for every entry and DP(i,j) would be based on max value in column j-1. So I guess O(n^3).

Comment: @qwr It will be interesting to see if \$O(k n^2 )\$ is possible.

Comment: @Simd it is, I have such a solution, but I'm searching for something more efficient. I might have \$O(n^2 + k n \log n)\$ if you can go both up and down, but it doesn't work if you can only go up

Comment: @CommandMaster I would love to see your faster solution even though it doesn't apply to this specific problem

Comment: if you can go up and down and right, then you can just consider every column individually

Comment: @qwr You still have to restrict the number of horizontal lines of course

Comment: It's not clear to me why you wouldn't consider the very top and very bottom horizontal lines, because this means your dividing line would always go from bottom left to top right corner.

Answer (score 3):

Without the \$k\$ constraint, \$O(n^2)\$ is possible using a columnwise DP.

Define \$d[i,j]\$ as the maximum sum of columns \$0\$ to \$j\$, given some boundary line with a horizontal boundary above cell \$(i,j)\$, and \$c[i,j]\$ to be the column prefix sum up to row \$i\$.  Then
$$d[i,j] = \max_{i \le i' \le n}  d[i',j-1] + c[i,j]$$

This would take linear time, but since max is associative,  we can do it with prefix sums too:
$$ 
m[i,j] = \max (d[i,j], m[i+1,j]) = \max_{i \le i' \le n}  d[i',j] \\
d[i,j] = c[i,j] + m[i,j-1] \\
$$

As requested, here is python code:

```python
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [[-3, -2,  3,  2, -2],
     [ 3, -2, -2, -5, -3],
     [ 0,  3,  1,  1, -3],
     [ 1,  1,  2,  1, -1],
     [ 1,  1,  1, -3,  3]])
n = a.shape[0]

d = np.zeros((n+1, n))
c = np.zeros((n+1, n))
m = np.zeros((n+1, n))

for j in range(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        c[i,j] = c[i-1,j] + a[i-1,j] if i > 0 else 0
        d[i,j] = c[i,j] + (m[i,j-1] if j > 0 else 0)

    for i in range(n,-1,-1):
        m[i,j] = d[i,j] if i == n else max(d[i,j], m[i+1,j])


print(d, max(d[:,-1]))
```

Finally, the added condition \$K\$ is a third parameter of the DP counting down how many new horizontal lines are left to use. This requires keeping track if the horizontal boundary row has changed in the max operation. In your example, you don't count the very bottom \$i=n\$ horizontal boundary, so this requires a special case to handle. Since you don't count the very top \$i=0\$ boundary either, your final result could look at \$d[0,n-1,K]\$ for the top row and \$d[1:n,n-1,K-1]\$ for the rest below.  You should verify that this implements your problem correctly.

(This may also work if you modify the problem to allow the boundary line to go up and down.)

$$d[i,j,k] = c[i,j] + \max(d[i,j-1,k], \max_{i < i' < n} d[i', j-1, k-1], d[n,j-1,k])$$

With max prefix sum:
$$
m[i,j,k] = \max(d[i,j,k], m[i+1,j,k]) \\
d[i,j,k] = c[i,j] + \max(d[i,j-1,k], m[i+1,j-1,k-1], d[n,j-1,k])
$$

```python
K = 1
d = np.zeros((n+1, n, K+1))
c = np.zeros((n+1, n))
m = np.zeros((n, n, K+1))

for j in range(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        c[i,j] = c[i-1,j] + a[i-1,j] if i > 0 else 0

        for k in range(K+1):
            d[i,j,k] = c[i,j]
            if j > 0:
                d[i,j,k] += max(d[i,j-1,k],
                                d[n,j-1,k],
                                m[i+1,j-1,k-1] if i+1 < n and k > 0
                                else -np.inf)

    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        for k in range(K+1):
            m[i,j,k] = max(d[i,j,k], m[i+1,j,k] if i+1 < n else -np.inf)


for k in range(K+1):
    print(d[:,:,k])

print(max(d[0,-1,K], max(d[1:n,-1,K-1])))
```

The final time complexity is  \$O(n^2 k)\$.

Comment: Could you add a version in Python too please for those who find it easier to read code.

Comment: I haven't worked out exactly how k works. If I have the energy I'll put a simple implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JavaScript:

```js
const _staircase = (rowIndex, colIndex, prevRowIndex, maxRowIndex, k, sum, rowIndices) => {
  result.numIterations += 1;
  if (maxRowIndex === 0 || k === kMax) {
    rowIndices += (',' + prevRowIndex).repeat(width - colIndex);
    for (let j = colIndex; j < width; j++) sum += c[prevRowIndex][j];
    colIndex = width; // skip further iteration
  }
  if (colIndex === width) { // extract result
    if (sum > result.sum) [result.sum, result.rowIndices] = [sum, rowIndices];
    return;
  }
  const kInc = colIndex === 0 && rowIndex === height ? 0 : rowIndex !== prevRowIndex;
  _staircase(0, colIndex + 1, rowIndex, rowIndex, k + kInc, sum + c[rowIndex][colIndex], rowIndices + ',' + rowIndex);
  if (rowIndex < maxRowIndex) _staircase(rowIndex + 1, colIndex, prevRowIndex, maxRowIndex, k, sum, rowIndices);
};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVdb5swFH3Pr7iTpoIVQpNUk6bStNpjJnWTtr0xtHrUBCfERMak7dr89u76C0i6p0mJsO/n8bkHs6Z72uSS79Rk//G1aEWueC2gUZTLnDYs3FIl@WMEm1v6SOB5BHB@DiumIG@3bUUV3zNo2m0DXACjeQl5XbVbgXF5LRoFacn4qlQRPPB7VWawgNSWjCsmVqqMwG7TaeYsWdIl5xjuord0F8r6ARbXgI@4qXjOQkJ0bFFLCCuExDF8luDjCmxXXI/HBEMGQWsMmib4uLKQcOljsG3Ks3StUeIKJjAzu7HHaJy6JS8g1IzAYoHVLC8nQKZDILrUAIxtFBe8qsKpOQOALYdhuDtoBuJWNCUvVCjYA3ySkj6FBjDxeSTRs9D9ylryP7VQtIKKCwarGujvGidjcY86QiVr2kphm2cQ7XapmKR63s0lTCM9xkuYLEXBBVdPkeZ5Ke6RZ3QHQQSH5NXX@dUJBGuFNpChSnD4brWTbP@ts2/pY7/ZmFbD@kSP1XJoEcZH6GDseLHED4pZ/uHlBTZm2avU1Ooa6AphEAU4yiEwEku2Y1RZYnFIHr@byYlsvPeNevR5dIs8HVb3YjHzdqlYxeXh6JoN30HRSlUyCdwf12QcutP2mQuXiwfU2exRSZr7mbo@OkODufZE4oZA2m8i7@jJMS/lyUQ64JKpVopkAMoqYLMU@YASN4izM5DD0Tj136Drsve8Q8@QKFu911Q47ZWEE5tF0CusX23QpVFEln0kX3bE@@wsOhIBWAn4ONJrqsN2NdQqGYLqQgyi/1W6eb31i3R8XPvzd6XdBQHpr0Iu8qq916/bm/nFza7iSsubuHtxNkj0Mjm6SfVhIuDEX6fGtqdVyyJYG6u@u1xPfQXegPHiFINJYK9dqwy4e//8@fvXL3GDxcWKF0@hBUgOP8UblwNDDnfJ6DAadd8b/KD8YI26NQhD@wa7@qmZUTq5iGAyjwAfc73KImt3ZvP/gP8L75ia2Jn59Va7n1vr7NhqAjErQ2Nm8FkGLW9I4AnKxPnx6oG53dQVi6t6Ff7j@6lJe/0L)

The function is a closure that iterates the pre-computed static matrix `c` recursively. The pre-computed matrix holds cumulative column sums and has a row of zeros prepended.

The paths that are followed are stored by concatenating 1-indexed row numbers in `rowIndices` which is a simple delimited text string like `,5,5,5,1,0`.

The function keeps track of how deep to go in each column by observing `maxRowIndex`. The first `if()` is a simple optimization that skips iteration of further columns when we're on the first row (that only contains zeros in `c`) and when we're out of horizontal lines to insert.

The harness is at the TIO link above. It constructs `c`, calls the recursive function, and shows the result.

Comment: What is the running time of this code?

Comment: Not sure. Looks like \$O(n^2)\$ but haven't really checked.

Comment: I would assume it depends on k too but I don't read JS. Could you explain what it is does?

Comment: _"you can assume \$k \leq \sqrt{n}\$"_ The code is [self-explanatory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self%2Dexplanatory).

Comment: @doubleunary no it's really not self-explanatory. At least what the main idea is.

Comment: @qwr Edited the answer to add a brief explanation and a TIO link.

Comment: Great update. Thx

Comment: Both answers \$O(kn^2)\$ were great. I only gave the reward to the other one because it had the math explanation first.

Comment: Obviously I'm biased but I find my answer much easier to reason about :P

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraint that the partition line may only move up or right, this corresponds to the number of combination words defined by north-east lattice-paths: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path

For example, for n=3, we would write:

```python
NNN
NNE
NEE
ENN
EEN
EEE
```

The total number of paths is:
`C(n+n,n) = C(2n,n)`

This is the central binomial coefficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

> This next section may be considered as speculation on a technicality.

By this constraint you can define that the left-side contains no entries while the right-side contains all entries:

```python
NNN
```

Or that the left-side contains all entries and the right-side contains no entries.

```python
EEE
```

These considers the following sub-cases:

- The maximal left-side partition is the entire matrix, because every entry is positive.
- The maximal left-side partition is empty, because the right-side partition contains negative integers for every entry. Subsequently, the entire matrix contains negative entries.

---

Calculate the total value of the matrix based on the left-hand side of the partition created by the NE path.
Words of 'N' and 'E' string movements corresponds from the bottom-left to the top-right corner.

```python
def calculate_partition_value(matrix, path):
    n = matrix.shape[0]
    row, col = n - 1, 0  # Start from the bottom-left corner
    total_value = 0

    # Track boundary created by the path
    boundary = [(row, col)]

    for move in path:
        if move == 'N':
            row -= 1  # Move up
        elif move == 'E':
            col += 1  # Move right
        boundary.append((row, col))

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if is_left_of_path((i, j), boundary):
                total_value += matrix[i, j]

    return total_value
```

Determine if a cell is on the left-hand side of the path based on the boundary coordinates by checking if the cell is below any segment, then return True. Otherwise, the cell is either right of the path or above, return False.

```python
def is_left_of_path(cell, boundary):
    for k in range(1, len(boundary)):
        if cell[1] < boundary[k][1] and cell[0] > boundary[k][0]:
            return False
    return True
```

Sort matrices based on the partition value:

```python
def sort_matrices_by_value(matrices_with_values):
    return sorted(matrices_with_values, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

And to provide a simpler example,
create an nxn matrix with random integers between -1 and 1.

```python
def randomize_matrix_entries(n):
    return np.random.randint(-1, 1+1, size=(n, n))
```

Ungolfed code:

```python
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

def generate_ne_paths(n):
    steps = 'N' * n + 'E' * n
    return set([''.join(p) for p in combinations(steps, n)])

def randomize_matrix_entries(n):
    return np.random.randint(-1, 1+1, size=(n, n))

def calculate_partition_value(matrix, path):
    n = matrix.shape[0]
    row, col = n - 1, 0
    total_value = 0
    boundary = [(row, col)]

    for move in path:
        if move == 'N':
            row -= 1
        elif move == 'E':
            col += 1
        boundary.append((row, col))

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if is_left_of_path((i, j), boundary):
                total_value += matrix[i, j]

    return total_value

def is_left_of_path(cell, boundary):
    for k in range(1, len(boundary)):
        if cell[1] < boundary[k][1] and cell[0] > boundary[k][0]:
            return False
    return True

def sort_matrices_by_value(matrices_with_values):
    return sorted(matrices_with_values, key=lambda x: x[1])

n = 3
ne_paths = generate_ne_paths(n)
matrices_with_values = []

for path in ne_paths:
    matrix = randomize_matrix_entries(n)
    value = calculate_partition_value(matrix, path)
    matrices_with_values.append((matrix, value, path))

sorted_matrices = sort_matrices_by_value(matrices_with_values)

print("First sorted matrix (example):")
print("Matrix:\n", sorted_matrices[0][0])
print("Total Value:", sorted_matrices[0][1])
print("Path:", sorted_matrices[0][2])
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE, nice first answer.

Comment: What is the resulting time complexity? The asymptotic complexity for computing all paths is exponential.